# Best way to make constant data file for an application?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have about 50.000 text file (~5KB each). I need make data file one time, then my app read (**not write**) to use.

I'm finding a way to keep all these file to one (or several) file. Current I store it in a .zip file, then when run app, I read zip file and get the entry I need. This way is very slow to read data (about 2 seconds).

Is any way I can store data that both fast to use and convenient to tranfer app between computer? Thank!

*[Edit: I'm not well work with data before, and my app is portable. Data is one-time create, no modify after create, and is plain text but have structure]*

Data structure:

```
Section abcd
  Item 1234
  Item klmn
Section def
  Item ...
  Item ...
...
  ...
```

Comment: Have you heard of MS SQL Server?

Comment: May even be interested in SQLite.....

Comment: Another question: Why do you have 50.000 very small text files?! I don't think that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Yes, but my app is portable, and I need it is convenient to tranfer between computer.

Comment: If you have a portable app, you could use an access database. It is more or less just a single file.

Comment: If content is very huge....how about storing the data in excel file?

Comment: It would be great if you could tell us, what kind of data you are storing. How often it changes and what you are acutally doing with this. Otherwise we are playing a good guessing game.

Comment: @user1567896: Data is plain text, but have structure. When my app load a file, it  will parse this file for futher action. And when create, it `will not change` anymore

Comment: Sorry, but that does not tell us very much at all. Do you provide this data? Is it 3. party data? Why don't you use several larger xml-files, a database, resource files etc.? There are many ways to optimize this but we can not help you if we don't know more details.

Comment: Do you store 50000 files in a zip file and it still only takes 2 seconds to get a file out of it?

Comment: there a so many options here, save to one delemetered textfile, xml, serialized class, json, sqlce, sqlite etc. Give more details if you want more help

Answer (score 0):

as a suggestion:

1. use the zip as primary source
2. before the app starts check if a specific folder exists

   if not - unzip the files there,
   if exists - check files count in the directory (as a dirty check that you do have data in the folder)
3. read files from the folder

Comment: This may work if the data does not change very often, otherwise it is not a good idea. But I don't think it is a good idea to have 50.000 small text-files at all.

Comment: I can imaging the case when the notion of a file is a requirement. for example the files are also consumed by 3rd party app in a way as they are

Comment: Not if anybody spent more than a second to think about the design :). How ever, unfortunately we do not know what the OP is doing or trying to achive ;).